# Программа на Java, которая проводит проверку нескольких API

Tags: java, http, api, rest, soap

Нужно разработать программу на Java, которая проводит проверку нескольких API компании (SOAP API, REST API, XML API, а также HTTP API) и показать ответ от каждого API, который выводит ответ: "Успех" или "API работает", или "Ошибка".

Каков наилучший подход, чтобы начать работу? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал jmeter, чтобы не кодить лишнего.

Или если надо именно свою отдельную программку написать, то взял бы Apache HttpСlient и просто бы написал пачку запросов, проверяя ответы. Можно конфигурационный файл прикрутить, в котором описывать какой запрос нужно сделать и что ожидать в ответе.